# Should a tag be created for Divinity: Original Sin 2?

Tags: discussion, tags

Divinity: Original Sin 2 was released September 14th 2017, and has many differences from its predecessor, Divinity: Original Sin. While some mechanics remain the same, many of the underlying systems that govern their use have changed completely, such that the two games play very differently.

Should a tag be created for this game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but tags can only exist when applied to questions.

If you have a question about a game that doesn't yet have a tag, you should create it when you ask the question. If you have less than [300 reputation points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), you can ask someone to create it for you in the comments. Just make it very clear in your question what the game is.

Comment: The question will be posted as soon as the site lets me; I didn't know the 40 minute wait between posts was shared between the base SE site and its metasite.